# Remove child div when parent is selected again

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, livequery

I am using an *n level selection chain* using 
[99 points website tutorial](http://www.99points.info/2010/12/n-level-dynamic-loading-of-dropdowns-using-ajax-and-php/),
but when I try to reselect parent node, the corresponding child div isn't reset.

I have searched all over StackOverflow and Google, but so far no luck.

Error is with the following code and I am unable to correct it.

```
    $(this).nextAll('.parent').remove();
    $(this).nextAll('label').remove();
```

This is my code

***Main Page***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.parent').livequery('change', function() {

                $(this).nextAll('.parent').remove();
            $(this).nextAll('label').remove();

                $.post("/dashboard/details/show_levels/", {
                    parent_id: $(this).val(),
                }, function(response){
                    setTimeout("finishAjax('levels', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
                });

                return false;
            });
        })

        function finishAjax(id, response){
        //alert(unescape(response));

          $('#'+id).append(unescape(response));
        } 
    </script>

    <div id=levels>
        <select id="level" class="parent" multiple="multiple" scroabble="1" name="data[level][]">
<option value="Building & Construction Mat">Building & Construction Mat</option>
<option value="Electronic Components">Electronic Components</option>
<option value="Furniture & Mattresses">Furniture & Mattresses</option>
<option value="Labels">Labels</option>
</select>
    </div>
```

**show_levels**

```
    <select id="sublevel" class="parent" multiple="multiple" scroabble="1" name="data[sublevel][]">
<option value="Labels">Labels</option>
<option value="Preparation Techniques">Preparation Techniques</option>
<option value="Process Parameters">Process Parameters</option>
</select>
```

### Update

Following code solved my problem

```
$("#levels").on('click', '.parent', function () {
    $(this).parents().nextUntil().remove();
});
```

Comment: Please post _your_ code here so we can debug without having to go to an external site.

Comment: live source html would help, not your php form helper code. Hierarchy structure is important to see due to traverse you are using

Comment: you're using the `.livequery()` provided with the demo which i think it's outdated cause it use jquery 1.3.2. you should use `.on()` (of course this will not solve your problem)

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I am using livequery with jquery 1.8.2 as there are other functions on application which are dependent on it and not comatible with jquery 1.3
So what do you suggest?

Comment: @charlietfl live html code updated

Comment: OK.. your `select` tag has no siblings so `next()`won't return anything. Maybe you want `$('.parent').not(this).remove()`   ?? Can't tell much from one element. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: @charlietfl No that also doesn't work, provided tutorial used exactly same binding (using class name), I want to maintain the hierarchy of the populated chained list.
Thanks for suggestion...

Comment: please create demo with enough html to replicate. Another tutorial is not a good source for the problem in your code. Replace `livequery` with `on` so won't need to include an old plugin file that is no longer needed in jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl I want to acheive the same thing as other tutorial has done.
Problem is when I select from parent node then nodes(lists) falling below that are not being reset instead new list are populated along with old lists

Comment: trying to help...but without enough html to replicate issue is not easy. The code in a working demo doesn't help, and it is unreasonable to need to have to sift through a whole tutorial to figure e out what's what

Comment: @charlietfl Thankyou for continuous support, code updated with more html

Comment: @Deadlock you should remove `.livequery()` and use `.live()` which is jquery native.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the reference to the `.livequery()` plugin and use directly `.live()`

[in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM3Nn/) i've replicated the tutorial using the `.live()` functionality to show you how to use it

Comment: I am fetching data from database each time so I want dynamic level chained list, but here I should know all the outcomes.. BTW Thanks for answer..

Comment: @Deadlock the fiddle use a _fake_ list only to demonstrate the use of `.live()`, hope to have helped

Comment: I am passing array as values from my controler so i have to manipulate it in JavaScript first and also live function is depreciated from jquery 1.8... thanks for helping..

Comment: yup, didn't know it was deprecated.
instead of `.live(event, func)` now is preferred to use `$(parentselector).on(event, childselector, func)` so, in your case it will be `$('#levels').on('click', '.parent', function(){})`

Comment: I have updated main post and problem is solved now by using nextUntil
BTW voted up for your efforts.. Thank you.. :)